# Interaction Flow Modeling Language (IFML) tools

Tags: web-applications, spring-webflow

Which other development environments unless Webratio can work with IFML (Interaction Flow Modeling Language)?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to their proprietary tools, WebRatio also offers an open source Eclipse plugin for editing IFML. http://www.webratio.com/portal/content/en/download-ifml-editor?link=oln266n.redirect&nav=page36.35